# spark-ec2 cannot stop running cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, cluster-computing

Using command `spark-ec2`, I've created a cluster with name "ruofan-large-cluster" within a virtual private cloud (vpc) on AWS-EC2. The cluster contains one master and two slave nodes, and it works very well. Now I would like to stop the cluster for a while, and then restart it. However, when I type the bash command as follow:

`$ ./spark-ec2 --region=us-east-1 stop ruofan-large-cluster`

It showed up the following output:

```
Are you sure you want to stop the cluster ruofan-large-cluster?
DATA ON EPHEMERAL DISKS WILL BE LOST, BUT THE CLUSTER WILL KEEP USING SPACE ON
AMAZON EBS IF IT IS EBS-BACKED!!
All data on spot-instance slaves will be lost.
Stop cluster ruofan-large-cluster (y/N): y
Searching for existing cluster ruofan-large-cluster in region us-east-1...
Stopping master...
Stopping slaves...
```

And it did not stop the cluster at all... I'm sure the information including both my cluster name and cluster region are both correct, and I also tried the following command to stop the cluster:

```
./spark-ec2 -k <key-file-name> -i <key-file> -r us-east-1 --vpc-id=<my-vpc-id> --subnet-id=<my-subnet-id> stop ruofan-large-cluster
```

It still showed the same output, and it didn't stop any cluster. I really do not know why the cluster is not stopped. I would appreciate if anyone helps me solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: No idea. We use `stop` all the time and it works fine. What Spark version is this?

Answer (score 4):

@DanielDarabos Thank you for your comment! I spent several hours on this problem, and found the bug just now. Actually, I think the official Spark code `spark-ec2.py` has a bug for identifying cluster name so I can't stop clusters. I am using `spark-1.4.0`, and in most of cases, `spark-ec2.py` works very well if I directly launch clusters on AWS without subnet of vpc. However, if I launch my cluster on a subnet of a vpc on AWS, then `spark-ec2.py` is unable to find the cluster so I can't `stop` the cluster. Specifically, in `spark-ec2.py`, there is a small segment of code as below:

```
conn = ec2.connect_to_region(opts.region)
```

Whenever we do actions such as launch, login, stop or destroy the cluster, `spark-ec2` will firstly connect to the specified region using the above code, and then gets all satisfied instances by `reservations =conn.get_all_reservations(filter={some conditions})`. It works very well if I directly launch my cluster without subnet of vpc. If my cluster is in the subnet of vpc, then `conn.get_all_reservations()` gets nothing. Just now I modified the original code with `conn = ec2.connect_to_region(opts.region, aws_access_key_id="my_aws_access_key_id", aws_secret_access_key="my_aws_secret_access_key"), and everything such as stop, login, destroy, etc. works perfect. I am still figuring out the further reasons why this modification works :)

Comment: There are some [resolved issues relating to VPCs and spark-ec2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5246). Do you think this is a new one? If you could, I suggest opening a new issue on JIRA to make the devs aware of the problem.

Comment: @NickChammas Thanks for your comments! I just created an issue on Apache JIRA. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10191

Comment: @NickChammas I just added the description about the problem on Apache JIRA.